# Using "case" with "or" in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to execute this query in SQL Server but it didn't work :

```
Select Nom from tab
  WHERE 
Nom  LIKE
CASE WHEN libelle !='' then
  Nom1 
OR 
 Nom2  
else 
 Nom3
end
```

Any help wil be appreciate

UPDATE: Added from OP comment:

> I want to verify if libelle not empty nom like nom1 or like nom2 else (if libelle is empty) nom like nom3

Comment: Any definition of "didn't work" would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the `OR` mean here? That doesn't make much sense any which way I read it.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here?  The `CASE` statement doesn't make much sense.  Maybe posting some data and then the desired result would be helpful

Comment: Answering questions like this one is a waste of time for everyone. It is not possible to answer because the question is so unclear. We don't know what you want.

Comment: For those who don't speak French, nom = name

Comment: @usr Actually, I think this is a good opportunity to show when it might be a good idea to use simple logical operators rather than a switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't feel that `case` is the right way to go here, so I'm seeing this as more like:

```
select Nom
from tab
where (
    libelle != ''
    and (
        Nom like Nom1
        or Nom like Nom2
    )
)
or (
    libelle = ''
    and Nom like Nom3
)
```

To me, this seems simpler to read and understand. The query optimizer might even agree.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Nom 
FROM tab
WHERE
   1 = CASE
         WHEN libelle != '' AND (Nom like Nom1 OR Nom like Nom2) THEN 1
         WHEN libelle = '' AND Nom like Nom3 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
```

(very similar to other options - especially Tim's)

Comment: +1 nice translation to a switch.

Answer (score 3):

So you're trying to do dynamic SQL then, I don't believe you can do it quite like that with a case statement, this could work though:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(100)
declare @libelle nvarchar(20)
--Set @libelle to something (can be via a query, or a stored proc parameter etc rather than just a string like here
set @libelle = ''
set @sql = 'SELECT Nom FROM tab WHERE Nom LIKE'

IF @libelle = ''
    SET @sql = @sql + ' ''Nom3'''
ELSE
    SET @sql = @sql + ' ''Nom1'' OR Nom LIKE ''Nom2'''
EXEC (@sql)
```

This should at least get you on the right path.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need to jump all the way up to using a procedure and dynamic SQL to do this. Also, wouldn't you have to run this multiple times (possibly for each row) and union the results since `libelle` is actually a column in the `tab` table and seemingly not a variable?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
   CASE WHEN libelle != '' THEN Nom1
        WHEN libelle /* OTHER CONDITION HERE */ THEN Nom2
        ELSE Nom3
   END
```

Comment: the problem that it's not an other condition, it's the same one

Comment: @user1805523 - What do you mean "it's the same one"? Do you want to return both `Nom1` and `Nom2` when `libelle != ''`?

Comment: Like @user1805523 said. What do you mean? What do you mean with "Nom1 
OR 
 Nom2" then?

Comment: @user1805523: Yes I mean that I want to return both Nom1 and Nom2 when libelle!=''